# Difference between "HAVING ... GROUP BY" and "GROUP BY ... HAVING"

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, group-by, having

I have got the table **MYTABLE** with 2 columns: **A** and **B**

I have got the following pieces of the code:

```
SELECT MYTABLE.A FROM MYTABLE 
    HAVING SUM(MYTABLE.B) > 100
    GROUP BY MYTABLE.A
```

and

```
SELECT MYTABLE.A FROM MYTABLE 
    GROUP BY MYTABLE.A
    HAVING SUM(MYTABLE.B) > 100
```

Is it the same? Is it possible that these 2 codes will return diffrent sets of results?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't know of any DBMS where your first query is legal syntax.

Comment: The difference is that the first one will fail and the second will not.

Comment: well at least we see sqlfiddle swallows it and does not complain at all http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9090b/2

Comment: Well, now I do know of 1 DBMS where the first is legal syntax. Every day is a school day.

Answer (score 9):

As documented, there is no difference. People are just used to seeing HAVING after GROUP BY.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF20040

> > Specify GROUP BY and HAVING after the where_clause and hierarchical_query_clause. If you specify both GROUP BY and HAVING, then they can appear in either order.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66e33/1

Answer (score 2):

I originally wrote:

> I am not sure your 1st query is valid. As far as I know, HAVING should always come after GROUP BY.

I was corrected by David Aldridge, the Oracle docs state that the order does not matter. Although I don't recommend using HAVING before GROUP for readability reasons (and to prevent confusion with a WHERE clause), it is technically correct. So that makes the answer to your question 'yes, it's the same'.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF20040

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I didn't know that. Although lexically it seems like a silly order. :) Will edit my answer.

Comment: It does seem strange but mostly I think that's unfamiliarity. If you think about it, it would really make sense for the FROM clause to come first - that's how I usually start writing a complex SQL statement, anyway.

Comment: Agreed, it does make a lot more sense to put the FROM first. Slightly off-topic: I heard that this was the actual reason MS made the FROM-clause come first when they designed LINQ (much inspired by SQL of course). They sort of had to, because otherwise it was nearly impossible for them to make things like code completion work in their IDE.

Comment: Also, changing things makes it seem like you're improving them -- why else change them?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `HAVING` before a `GROUP BY`, the `HAVING` is like the "`WHERE`" but for the `GROUP BY` condition.

Answer (score 0):

The clauses are evaluated in order. You can have a HAVING clause following immediately the FROM clause. In this case, the HAVING clause will apply to the entire rows of the result set. The select list may only contain, in this case, one/more/all of the aggregation functions contained in the HAVING clause.

So, your first query is not valid because of the above. A valid query would be

```
SELECT SUM(MYTABLE.B) AS s FROM MYTABLE 
HAVING SUM(MYTABLE.B) > 100
```

The above query will return one or no row, depending on whether the condition `SUM(MYTABLE.B) > 100` is verified or not.

Still, there is one more reason for which your first query is not valid. The GROUP BY clause may refer only to columns in the data set to which it applies. So going on with my valid query above, you can write the following valid query (though it will be useless and nonsense, as it is applied to either one or no rows):

```
SELECT SUM(s)
FROM 
(
SELECT SUM(MYTABLE.B) s
FROM MYTABLE 
HAVING SUM(MYTABLE.B) > 100
) q
GROUP BY s
```

So, just to answer: no, they're not the same. One of them is not even valid.

Comment: I don't know why you think this. It is documented that the two clauses can appear in either order, and the code works. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66e33/1

Comment: Well, in fact it looks like it's vendor-dependent. So we can't talk here about standard SQL. My answer was tested (and holds true for) on SQL Server 2008 R2. Indeed, Oracle supports the syntax in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

both WHERE and HAVING allow for the imposition of conditions in the query. Difference:
We use WHERE for the records returned by select from the table,
We use HAVING for groups returned by group by select query